# Visualizar "View" do Postgres no Mysql. É possível? Como Fazer?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, conexão, odbc

Existe alguma maneira de visualizar uma View criada no Postgres e visualizar no MySQL? Se sim, como configurar?

Comment: Já viu isto ?      https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/storage-engines/connect/connect-table-types/connect-table-types-odbc-table-type-accessing-tables-from-other-dbms/

Comment: @Motta esse table connect é bem parecido o o federated engine no mysql. Pena que o mysql só suporta ele mesmo.

Comment: eu sei que o postgresql pode acessar o mysql, não tenho certeza quanto ao caminho inverso: http://pgxn.org/dist/mysql_fdw/

Answer (score 1):

Não, um banco não pode acessar o outro. O que você pode fazer é, construir uma aplicação que servirá como uma bridge entre esses dois servers e usar um dataset para alimentar um outro com as informações da view em questão.

Comment: Na verdade sim, um banco pode acessar o outro: [Linked Server no SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx), [Database link Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm)

Comment: @gmsantos O problema é ter essas funcionalidades no MySQL e no PostgreSQL.

Comment: Do lado do Postgre existem os [Foreign Data Wrappers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers), infelizmente eu não conheço um equivalente para o MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que isso não é possível. O MySQL possui um *engine* `FEDERATED` para conectar a bancos externos. Infelizmente, a versão atual do MySQL (5.7) limita acesso federado a outros bancos MySQL ([link para a documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-usagenotes.html)).

[MariaDB](https://mariadb.org), um *fork* do MySQL possui uma *engine* [`CONNECT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connect-odbc-table-type-accessing-tables-from-another-dbms/) capaz de acessar o PostgreSQL através de OBDC, mas até onde vai meu conhecimento esse *engine* não é compatível com MySQL.

---

**Fonte**: [*SOen - Do databases besides Postgres have features comparable to foreign data wrappers?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464660/664577)